# Creating a Persistance Unit in Netbeans - Need JNDI name

Tags: java, netbeans, ejb-3.1

I am trying to create a persistence unit using Netbeans. However I cant figure out what the Jndi Name should be - In the database connect I have successfully managed to connect to my Db?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

what i usually do is that I setup the datebase connection in the server "container", so that depends on the server you're using. and the JNDI name I put in the server would be something similar to `java:comp/env/jdbc/employee`